# Can I force svn update when maven package

Tags: java, svn, maven, package

Sometimes I forget to svn update before package when I work with my colleague on same project. Can I force svn update whenever I do a maven package?

Comment: I recommend you don't tangle your SCM and Maven in this way. Maven builds should only depend on the checked out source code (and any declared dependencies). Developers are used to the 'checkout, build, test' cycle, but they don't expect the build part of that to mess with the SCM.

Comment: @artbristol I can't understand exactly. What can be the problem? Could you give me some examples?

Comment: When you're working on a checkout, you don't expect its files to change. If you force svn update during the course of a build, that means any checkins made will automatically show up. That is massively confusing.

Comment: @artbristol That's right. There's pros and cons, so using it is depends on project I think. In my project we usually don't work on same part, so it won't so much confusing.

Comment: Respectfully disagree. It's best to stick to standard project workflows, especially when your system is part of a larger one.

Comment: @artbristol Then how do you prevent the situation that someone make a package without SVN update?

Comment: Maven `package` phase is for building a binary jar/war/etc. on the developer's local machine. To release a finished artifact, you use the `deploy` phase. The maven-release-plugin will help with your SCM problems by checking for modified files in the checkout, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`scm:update`](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/update-mojo.html) goal of maven-scm-plugin.